# Navbar Centered Without Extending Background With It

Tags: html, css, navbar

I might be missing something blatantly obvious but for some reason, I cannot get my dropdown nav menu to center underneath my flavors button without it dragging the entire header down with it. I'm not sure how to proceed, it's not a major issue as it's nothing that's going to take away from what I'm trying to display but it would be a lot cleaner if it wouldn't do what it's doing.
[image]
[image]

```css
body {
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
}

.navbar {
  overflow: hidden;
  background-image: url("https://i.imgur.com/dxqafWb.png");
  background-repeat: repeat;
  background-size: auto;
  background-blend-mode: soft-light;
  background-color: #AAAAAA;
}

.navbar a {
  font-size: 16px;
  color: #330300;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 14px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.dropdown {
  overflow: hidden;
}

.dropdown .dropbtn {
  font-size: 16px;
  border: none;
  outline: none;
  color: #330300;
  padding: 14px 16px;
  background-color: inherit;
  font-family: inherit;
  margin: 0;
}

.navbar a:hover, .dropdown:hover .dropbtn {
  background-color: darkgray;
}

.dropdown-content {
  display: none;
  position: relative;
  background-image: url("https://i.imgur.com/dxqafWb.png");
  background-position: center;
  background-repeat: repeat;
  background-size: auto;
  background-blend-mode: soft-light;
  background-color: #AAAAAA;
  min-width: 160px;
  max-width: 200px;
  box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
  z-index: 1;
}

.dropdown-content a {
  float: none;
  color: #330300;
  padding: 12px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: block;
  text-align: center;
}

.dropdown-content a:hover {
  background-color: darkgray;
}

.dropdown:hover .dropdown-content {
  display: block;
}

.logo {
  max-width: 50%;
  height: auto;
  float: none;
  text-align-last: center;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>VapeJoose</title>

  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">

  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/index.css">
</head>

<body>
  <center>
  <header class="header">
    <div class="navbar">
      <div class="logo">
        <img src="css/img/logo.png" class="logo">
      </div>
      <a href="index.html">Home</a>
      <a href="about.html">About Me</a>
      <a href="contact.html">Contact Me</a>
      <a href="order.html">Order Search (Coming Soon)</a>
      <div class="dropdown">
        <button class="dropbtn">Flavors
        </button>
        <div class="dropdown-content">
          <a href="fruit.html">Fruit Flavors</a>
          <a href="desert.html">Desert Flavors</a>
          <a href="cereal.html">Cereal Flavors</a>
          <a href="candy.html">Candy Flavors</a>
          <a href="beverages.html">Beverages Flavors</a>
          <a href="menthol.html">Menthol Flavors</a>
          <a href="tobacco.html">Tobacco Flavors</a>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </header>
  <!-- ^ header ^ -->
</center>
<p>test</p>
</body>

<footer>

</footer>

</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`.dropdown-content` have `position: relative`. Make it absolute and if you want to center it relative to `.dropdown` you need also add this:

```
.dropdown {
    position: relative;
}
.dropdown-content {
    left: 50%;
    transform: translateX(-50%);
}
```

And don't forget to remove `overflow: hidden` from parents of `.dropdown-content`, else your `.dropdown-content` block would be hidden.